# Is it possible to use roxygen comment in LaTeX?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, roxygen2

I have a couple of functions with roxygen comments, like this:

```
#' Read data from Subversion repository
#'
#' @param path Path to the local git repository. Must be read accessible.
#' @param data_to_read A character vector of any length.
#' Can be equal to \code{"all"} or contain any combination of the following:
#' * \code{"revision"} - Revision number.
#'
#' @return Data frame 
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' load_from_svn("~/my_repo/")
```

Now, I want to somehow insert generated documentation (`.Rd`) into a LaTeX document. My LaTeX compiler supports `knitr`, but I don't see any way to possibly convert R documentation format to either R markdown or `.Rtex` format.

Is it possible to convert `.Rd` into something parseable by `knitr` (or LaTeX in general)? Or R documentation files are completely separate from other forms of documentation and I have to rewrite it into something more suitable?

Comment: Check out the `?Rdconv` or `?Rd2latex` help pages which have information about converting Rd into LaTeX

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I guess I'm supposed to define `HeaderA`, `Description` etc. myself?

Comment: @MrFlick Nevermind. I found that `Rd` package is needed and I need `Rd.sty` file, which I found here: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty . If you'd like to turn your comment into answer, I'll be happy to accept it, if not, I'll probably share how I made it in few days. Thanks again!